# ArrayList when making a game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Im wondering how to use an ArrayList/Array in this situation:

Lets say I want to make a pacman game, and I want there to be 250 ghosts. How do I store their position instead of writing them all myself (int ghost1x, int ghost1Y, int ghost2x, int ghost2y etc) ?

Also please show me some examples!
:)

Im using java

Comment: Java, sorry for not specifying

Comment: This question is much too broad, it's like asking "How do I program?". You should go and try something (maybe read an introductory book) and then come back when you have a specific problem with a piece of code you've written that doesn't work how you expect it. Then, the answers you get will be much more useful

Comment: Also, this question isn't going to be that useful to you. The answers depend almost entirely on the fact you've decided that an `ArrayList` is the right way to write this code, when actually you've still got a lot of architectural questions to ask before you know that this is the right decision to make. It's like building a house and starting by painting some plasterboard.

Answer (score 3):

Make the ghost class hold the x and y position, then make the ArrayList hold objects of the gost class and store all ghosts in it.

Then you loop trough the ArrayList of ghosts each game update with a foreach or something similar, and perform position updates.

I believe this is a fairly normal solution

```
private class Ghost{
public Ghost(int x, int y);//ctor
int x, y;
//other ghost code
}
private ArrayList<Ghost> ghosts = new ArrayList<Ghost>();
for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
ghosts.add(new Ghost(startX, startY));
}

//in the gameloop:
foreach(Ghost ghost in ghosts)
{
ghost.updatePositionOrSomething();
ghost.drawOrSomething();
}
```

That would be some ideas for the code, I havent written java in a while, so not 100% steady on the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a game developer, but what comes to mind is creating a Ghost object which contains two int variables to represent it's x/y coordinates.

Then create an array of Ghosts, and update as necessary in the game.

Does that help?

```
//Create Ghost array
private Ghost[] ghosts = new Ghost[250]

//Fill ghost array
for (int i = 0; i < 250; i ++)
{
   Ghost g = new Ghost();
   g.xCoor = 0;
   g.yCoor = 0;

   ghosts[i] = g;
}

//Update coordinates while program running
while(programRunning == true)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 250; i ++)
   {
      ghosts[i].xCoor = newXCoor;
      ghosts[i].yCoor = newYCoor;
   }
}

//Make Ghost class
public class Ghost 
{  
   public int xCoor {get; set;}
   public int yCoor {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I know, but how do I do that, thats my question

Comment: @user1658294 this is basic Object Oriented Programming, and you should read a book about, not just a couple of links.

Comment: I added some example code for you, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Sorry, .net syntax creeping in. They're just public int variables.

Comment: Interesting... I'll go try it out etc

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a deeper look into Object Orientated Designing.

You should create a Ghost class:

```
public class Ghost {

int x;
int y;

public void update() {

}

public void render() {

}

}
```

Now you can create an array of Ghost objects (you should only create a List<> if the amount of Ghost objects varies).

```
Ghost[] ghosts = new Ghost[250];
```

Now initialize the array of Ghosts:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ghosts.length(); i++) {
ghosts[i] = new Ghost();
}
```

I'll leave it up to you how you'll initialize the `x` and `y` coordinates.

I hope this helps.